# How does one understand Typescript Error message?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and trying to get my heads around error messages that typescript pukes. I've spent hours trying to search what does the does the following entail:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/Radio/styles.tsx:142:3
    TS2322: Type 'StyledComponent<"input", WireframeTheme, {}, never>' is not assignable to type 'StyledComponent<"input", WireframeTheme, RadioStyleProps, never>'.
  Type 'StyledComponent<"input", WireframeTheme, {}, never>' is not assignable to type 'StyledComponentBase<"input", WireframeTheme, RadioStyleProps, never>'.
    Types of property 'defaultProps' are incompatible.
      Type 'Partial<Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "children" | ... 284 more ... | "step"> & { ...; }, "children" | ... 285 more ... | "step"> & Partial<...>, "children" | ... 285 more ... | "step"> & { ...; }> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "children" | ... 284 more ... | "step"> & { ...; } & RadioStyleProps, "children" | ... 287 more ... | "hasIcon"> & Partial<...>, "children" | ... 287 more ... | "hasIcon"> & { ...; }> | undefined'.
        Type 'Partial<Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "children" | ... 284 more ... | "step"> & { ...; }, "children" | ... 285 more ... | "step"> & Partial<...>, "children" | ... 285 more ... | "step"> & { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "children" | ... 284 more ... | "step"> & { ...; } & RadioStyleProps, "children" | ... 287 more ... | "hasIcon"> & Partial<...>, "children" | ... 287 more ... | "hasIcon"> & { ...; }>'.
          Types of property 'size' are incompatible.
            Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
              Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

As far as I understand that there seems to be a type mismatch. But I have no idea for which component.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So somewhere, you're setting a property named `size` to the type `number | undefined`. Then something else somewhere is trying to use that property but it's failing to implement an interface that specifies `size` must only be a `number`.

Whatever object you're setting that property in is then used somewhere else, and somewhere else, and so on and so forth. That's why you see such a long list of these type errors.

Consider this simple example which is throwing a type error.

```
interface SomeType {
  size: number,
}

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  let someSetting = "small";

  const getSize = () => {
    if (someSetting === "large") {
      return 100;
    }
  }

  let myVar: SomeType = {
    size: getSize(), // This line has a type error.
  };

  return null;
}
```

The type `SomeType` says that size must always be a number and nothing else. My component is trying to make a variable called `myVar` which *must* implement the SomeType interface. So to set `size`, I'm calling the function `getSize` which will return 100 in one case but undefined in another case. This is causing a type error. It becomes a little more obvious why when I add a type to the getSize function like so:

```
const getSize = (): number | undefined => {
  if (someSetting === "large") {
    return 100;
  }
}
```

Now you can plainly see that the function returns `number | undefined`. Typescript is reporting the error:

```
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
App.tsx(17, 3): The expected type comes from property 'size' which is declared here on type 'SomeType'
```

To fix the issue, I just need to track down where I'm setting a property to the wrong type and then ensure that I always set the type correctly. Here is how I'd fix the getSize() method so that it always returns a number:

```
const getSize = () => {
  if (someSetting === "large") {
    return 100;
  } else {
    return 50;
  }
}
```

Now there is no way for the `getSize()` function to return anything other than a number and I've resolved the type error.

Comment: May I know how I should read the message ? From top to bottom or the other around? I am confused which end is the starting